# Only last value pushed to array

Tags: javascript, primes

I am working on prime numbers algorithm, and I almost finished it.. I think output array is updated every time loop finishes, so if I call function with prime number: e.g `primes(7)`, I get `[7]` instead of `[2,3,5,7]`. If its called with non prime, output arr is empty.

Here is code:

```
function rimes(num){
    var outputArr = [];

    for(var i=1; i<=num; i++){  
        function range(start, count) {
            return Array.apply(0, Array(count))
                    .map(function (element, index) { 
                             return index + start;  
                         });
        }
        var rangeArr = range(1,num);
        var current = i;

        function rangeFiltering(value){
            return value !== 1 && value < current;
        }
        var filteredRange = rangeArr.filter(rangeFiltering);

        function dividingByEachRangeElement(rangeElement){
          return current % rangeElement !== 0;
        }
        var divided = filteredRange.filter(dividingByEachRangeElement);

        if(divided.length === num - 2){  //current is prime if there are all numbers from 1 to current in divided array.(if there are zeros after modulo) i.e. when current is 5(prime), divided array is [2,3,4]. When current is 6(non prime), divided arr is [4,5] - 2,3 are missing because 6%2 = 0 and 6%3 = 0. 
            outputArr.push(current);
        }
    }
    console.log(outputArr);
}
sumPrimes(47);


//sumPrimes(6)  -> [];
//sumPrimes(7)  -> [7];
//sumPrimes(11) -> [11];
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: If you add console.log(outputArr) to the for-loop, this will cause it to output the array every loop. You can tell that it does not add anything to the array until the last loop, so this is your problem.

Comment: did you try to debug it? why not add e.g. `console.log(divided.length)` below the definition for `divided`, to see what's going on?

Comment: You seem to recalculate `rangeArr` for every `i`, using the same parameters every time. I don't think that is needed - it would be better to build it once, before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on the line:

`if(divided.length === num - 2)`

which means the current number is only added to `outputArr` if the length of `divided` happens to equal `num - 2` which is only true when `i` or `current` is equal to `7` in your example case.

Changing it to:

`if(divided.length === current - 2)`

should do the trick.

Comment: Haha, I need coffee.. Thanks!